# NSBatchUpdateRequest: .Update not firing in didChangeObject

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am building a blog reader while learning Swift. In this I am saving the data to Core Data and having the option to mark the articles as "read". When I mark them individually as read using editActionsForRowsAtIndexPath the tableview.reloadData() works and the cell formatting changes.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let object = fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    var edit = UITableViewRowAction()
    if let read = object.valueForKey("read") as? Bool{
        if read == true{
            edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Mark\nUnread") { action, index in
                object.setValue(false, forKey: "read")
                do{
                    try context.save()
                }catch{

                }
                tableView.reloadData()
                self.updateReadAll()
            }
            edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: "#A1A19E")
        }else{
            edit = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Mark\nRead") { action, index in
                object.setValue(true, forKey: "read")
                do{
                    try context.save()
                }catch{

                }
                tableView.reloadData()
                self.updateReadAll()
            }
            edit.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: "#A1A19E")
        }
        return [edit]
    }else{
        return []
    }
}
```

However, when I use NSBatchUpdateRequest the Core Data updates but the cell formatting does not update. I have to force quit the app and relaunch for the cells to appear correctly. I added print("Updated") in didChangeObject to verify it wasn't the configureCell causing the issue.

```
@IBAction func markReadAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    let appDel: AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext
    let table = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "BlogItems")
    table.propertiesToUpdate = ["read":true]
    do{
        try context.executeRequest(table)
    }catch{

    }
    updateReadAll()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func controller(controller: NSFetchedResultsController, didChangeObject anObject: AnyObject, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath?, forChangeType type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: NSIndexPath?) {
        switch type {
            case .Update:
                self.configureCell(tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath!)!, atIndexPath: indexPath!)
                print("Updated")
            case .Insert:
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Delete:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            case .Move:
                tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
                tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath!], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        }
}

func configureCell(cell: UITableViewCell, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let object = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    cell.textLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("title")!.description
    cell.detailTextLabel!.text = object.valueForKey("snippet")!.description
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(hexaString: "#F8F7F5")
    cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    if let read = object.valueForKey("read") as? Bool{
        if read == true{
            cell.textLabel!.textColor = UIColor(hexaString: "#A1A19E")
            cell.detailTextLabel!.textColor = UIColor(hexaString: "#A1A19E")
        }
    }
}

func updateReadAll(){
    if searchCoreData(NSPredicate(format: "read = %@", false)) > 0{
        markReadView.enabled = true
        markReadView.tintColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    }else{
        markReadView.enabled = false
        markReadView.tintColor = UIColor(hexaString: "#A1A19E")
    }
}
```

Does the didChangeObject not work with batch updates? Is there something else I can do to update the cells?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the video from 2014 WWDC about Batch Updates.  Basically the updates are made on disk but your in memory copy of the data is **NOT** updated.  You must update the objects in memory yourself, either resetting the context or refreshing each object individually.